# Botão dropdown não funciona

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Botão dropdown não funciona, fica aparecendo o `#` lá em cima mas não abre.

Alguém por favor pode me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="menu"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<title>estocaki</title>

<script language="JavaScript" src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="script/maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />


</head>
<body>
    <div >
        <img src="img/Estocaki.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="menu" class="span12 ">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                <li role="presentation" ><a href="menu.php">Home</a></li>

                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown" >
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Cadastrar<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="cad-produto.php">Cadastro de Produtos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cad-forn.php">Cadastro de Fornecedores</a></li>
                    </ul>       

                </li>

                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cadastrar Categoria e Un. de Medida</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cadastro de Entrada</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cadastro de Saída</a></li>

                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown" >
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Relatórios<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Relatório de Entrada</a></li>
                    </ul>       

                </li>

                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Lista de Fornecedores</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="login.php">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seu código está incompleto, estão faltando os CSS e JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 1):

Verifiquei que você está usando um menu do `bootstrap` e nesse caso é necessário que o `javascript` dessa biblioteca também esteja inserido.

Abaixo da chamada do `jquery` chame o `bootstrap`, segue como vai ficar:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

É necessário que o arquivo `script/jquery.js` e o `bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js` exista na pasta, então verifique.

Sempre quando tiver esses tipo de problemas verifique se o caminho dos arquivos estão corretos e se não está dando nenhum erro de JavaScript no console do navegador.